# jQuery ignores last element in returned set

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm working on an internal plugin for jQuery dataTables, and I'm experiencing weird behavior.

Take a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bJLLz/

The code below is looking for every 'tr' first 'td' element, and adds another 'td' with a checkbox input before every match it finds. (Notice the last row in the fiddle above does not have a checkbox)

```
$(function () {
    var checkBox = $('<input>', {
        "type": "checkbox"
    })
    var td = $('<td/>', {
        'class': "table-checkbox"
    }).insertBefore("tbody > tr > td:first-child")

    var checkBoxes = $(checkBox).appendTo(td)
    var th = $('<th/>', {
        'class': 'text-center'
    }).insertBefore("thead > tr:nth(0) > th:nth(0)")

    $(checkBox).appendTo(th)
        .change(function () {
        $(this).is(":checked") ? checkBoxes.prop('checked', true) : checkBoxes.prop('checked', false);
    })
})
```

Although jQuery is adding the relevant 'td' element, the last 'td' in the table is added, but without the checkbox input..

This is really unexpected.. Does any one have any idea why ?

Comment: I think it's more amazing that it works? You're not creating a new checkbox for every row, but one checkbox that you insert in every row, and insertBefore must be doing something internally that creates a new checkbox for every row, and not just moving the one you've created etc ?

Comment: @adeneo That's how `.insertBefore()` works. It's meant to be used to copy one element to multiple places.

Comment: @Juhana - well, yes, but this seems counterintuitive to me, I'd much rather do the iterating myself and do this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bJLLz/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does it:

```
$(checkBox).appendTo(th)
```

Unlike `.insertBefore()`, `.appendTo()` *moves* the element to the new position. After all the other operations before that line `checkBox` refers to the checkbox on the last row of the table.

You need to make a copy of the checkbox before appending it:

```
$(checkBox).clone().appendTo(th)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJLLz/1/)

Comment: Thanks, That works. On a side note, is this the best way to achieve that result?

Comment: Eh, it's as good as anything. Although I'd use `:first` instead of `:nth(0)` and `:first-child`.

Comment: I can't use :first since I have to find every "tr" > td:first-child

Answer (score 1):

Juhana was totally right about your issue, but i saw an opportunity to fix it up a bit. I simplified your code quite a bit and used some event delegation to handle the `change` event.

```
$(function () {

    $('table').on('change', '.row-checkbox', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlighted', this.checked);
    });

    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td,th').first().before(function () {
          return '<td><input type="checkbox" class="row-checkbox"></td>';
        });
    });

});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bJLLz/2/

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider using it. :)